# A situation to compare time taken by two objects

Tags: kinematics, home-experiment

This randomly came up in my mind.

> suppose a bead like particle P at A in a frictionless hemispherical bowl. It is released from A at t = 0. A horizontal velocity v is imparted to bead P. A bead Q of the same mass as P is ejected from A at the same time along the horizontal string AB, with the speed v. Friction between the bead and the string may be neglected.
> Which bead reaches point B earlier?

Kindly neglect the distortion in shape they are perfect point particles
[image: n]

---

For a particle moving along the string

$T=2R/v$

Particle along spherical surface gave me a tough time and I feel it undergoes a circular motion so time would be half of its vertical time period but I can't calculate the time period of a vertical circle.

Is there an intuitive approach for this?

Comment: Here normal force always acts towards a common centre so we can consider this to be a situation of of a pendulum tied with a string and you need to use pendulum time period formula

Comment: Huh why does this look so eerily similar to a JEE sample question which I had done?

Comment: "Suppose a particle A in a frictionless hemispherical bowl. It is released at A at t = 0." ... the particle is A and it is released at a particle..?

Comment: What's the nature of particle compared to the bead?

Comment: If P is given a horizontal velocity at A, it is likely to leave the surface of the bowl.

Comment: @R.W.Bird man it's on a string not on bowls surface

Comment: How does it being on a string suggest that it won't exit the bowl at end of motion?

Comment: @Buraian even if exits we are to find who reaches first

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that the horizontally moving particle has no extra forces on it whilst the particle rolling down the ramp has the 'normal force' accelerating it while it moves till bottom and then normal force 'deaccelerates' it as it rises again.

The reason is that while supporting its weight, the normal force also gives a horizontal component of force parallel to the surface to push the object (*). So, the thing is that even though totally it the velocity is the same at the end and starting point for both, the particle rolling down the ramp got pushed 'quicker' into the ending point.

For figuring out the time of the particle's motion it may be a bit complex,  but I myself have tried to do it and it turns out to be some complex math [(see here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3870100/block-with-point-mass-rolling-down-correlating-variables-and-symmetry)

---

*: Think of why objects move down ramps, this is also why we need frictions to keep things from sliding down ramps

On comment's by OP, I reference these other answers which discuss how 'constraint' forces accelerate object whilst no work is done

See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/512879/what-is-mean-by-the-statement-that-constraint-forces-do-no-work) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/524222/dalemberts-principle-and-the-work-done-by-constraint-forces-in-atwoods-machin?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: According do this isnt normal force doing some work. But this contradicts the fact that force perpendicular to displacement do 0 work

Comment: The normal force doesn't do work because it acts perpendicular to displacement at all points, however, it still accelerates. The work cancels of from the horizontal and vertical part ,

$$ N \cos \theta dx -N \sin \theta dy=0$$

Comment: Since,

$$ ds = dx \vec{i} + dy \vec{j}$$

$$ N = N \cos \theta \vec{i} + N \sin \theta \vec{j}$$

However, this question what you've asked is interesting and I personally think requires more discussion. Suggest asking it as another question.